# Magento 2 - Class Vendor\Module\Model\Cbdom_main does not exist?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate **Ccavenuepay** on my store, but when I click place order its giving me errors like

```
a:4:{i:0;s:60:"Class Magekmf\CcavenuepayEmi\Model\Cbdom_main does not exist";i:1;s:7558:"#0 /home/dell/workspace/local.magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magekmf\\Ccavenu...')
```

[image]

I have created Cbdom_main.php class as well but error does not resolve. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Change your class name **Cbdom_main** to **CbdomMain**. And modify where you use this inside your development.

Comment: It's not working for me!